# How to optimize mysql table for executing faster

Tags: mysql

I made a mysql database for my project. I need to know if what I did is correct or not.

I made a master table to store all my movie details and I built some other tables to store the views and ratings. Am I doing wrong by using different tables to store views and ratings, although I can use the master table to store views and rating in each post.

If I add the rating and views fields to the master table itself, will it affect my database? What's the optimal solution?

I am using Myisam as lots of select queries are needed instead of insert.

Comment: Need to be more precise. Optimize for what? Space or response time? What kind of queries are being posed to this database. Which storage engine are u using InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: It's good idea to split data and stats. Remember that aggregate functions sum,avg etc. are extremaly slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using the fields for incremental value, you can use the master table.
But if you wish to save extra parameters to a vote or view, you should use a secundary table.
e.g. You want to save which user voted which value on which date. Than you should add a table 'votes' with the fields:  voteId, userId, rating, date.

Afterwards you can use the AVG function to calculate the avarage vote.

Comment: thanx for ur response, i use the extra table for

Comment: For big tables never use aggragate functions. Compute statistics online or use another storage/db and use map reduce.

Comment: Ah ok, forgot to mention that :)